# Formating tbl_svysummary() outputs in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm doing descriptive analysis of survey data, I'm using the gtsummary package which have been working nicely.

I use this code, I don't provide any data because I'm sure I just need to add something to the arguments,

```
twbysexo_a<-estrato_a %>% tbl_svysummary(by= PB1,
                                         include = c(teletrab_3, PB1), 
                                         percent = "column", 
                                         missing = "no", 
                                         digits = ~2)%>%
    add_overall(last = T, col_label = "**Total**, N={N}")%>%
    modify_header(label = "Variable")

twbysexo_a
```

The output I get can be seen below.

[image: Printed output]

What I want is the output to exclude the row with the "teletrab_3" label, so it would look neater. By doing some cut of the image I would like it to look like this:

[image]

EDIT: As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8711276/daniel-d-sjoberg) commented adding the option `remove_row_type()` to the pipe made it work just fine:

```
twbysexo_a<-estrato_a %>% tbl_svysummary(by= PB1,
                                         include = c(teletrab_3, PB1), 
                                         percent = "column", 
                                         missing = "no", 
                                         digits = ~2)%>%
    add_overall(last = T, col_label = "**Total**, N={N}")%>%
    modify_header(label = "Variable")%>%
    remove_row_type(teletrab_3, type = "header")

twbysexo_a
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: You can use `gtsummary:::remove_row_type()` to remove the header rows for a catogorical variable summary. If you need further clarification, please update with a reproducible example.

Comment: this worked just fine!, I reviewed the documentation carefully but couldn't find this, would you mind to post this as an answer?.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg is there a way to get the r-markdown code as output instead of the printed html?